# C/++ Getting an std::map value that is a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, colors, return

I'm trying to make an easy to use dictionary that uses an std::map to store sprites. Sprites are stored as a 2D color array. [I think] I've set up the load method fine but am having trouble making a Get function. Returning multidimensional arrays seems rather tricky, and when trying to access the std::map value it expects me to specify an element in the Color type.

Header

```
class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary();
    ~Dictionary();
    void Add(std::string key, std::string fileName, int x, int y, int w, int h);
    void Remove(std::string key);
    Color** Get(std::string key);

private:
    std::map<std::string, Color[Tile::Width][Tile::Height]> dictionary;
};
```

Source

```
Color** Dictionary::Get(std::string key)
{
    return dictionary[key];
}
```

Comment: Array decaying only goes down one level. Without bother to double-check this, I'd say that the return value is going to be `Color (*)[Tile::Height]`. But why deal with this headache? Use `std::array<std::array<Color, Tile::Height>, Tile::Width>` and just return a reference to this.

Comment: Oh, neat. Didn't even know that was a thing. Ta

Comment: The C++ standard is about 2000 pages long. It will take a few years to know everything in it.